# Reduce object with array properties to a boolean that is true if any of the arrays is not empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object:

```
filters: {
  field1: [?],
  field2: [?],
  field3: [?],
  etc
}
```

The result I want is a `boolean` that states whether any of the filters arrays has something in ithem (i.e: is not empty).

Something lile:

```
const hasActiveFilters = Object.values(filters).reduce(...);
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.some` would be more appropriate, to test if any of the values in the values array fulfill a condition.

```
const hasActiveFilters = Object.values(filters).some(arr => arr.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any of the filter field arrays is not empty:

```js
const data = {
  filters: {
    field1: [],
    field2: [],
    field3: [],
  }
}

const hasActiveFilters = (filters) => Object.values(filters).some(a => a.length)

console.log(hasActiveFilters(data.filters))

data.filters.field2.push('xyz')

console.log(hasActiveFilters(data.filters))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try .some

```js
const filters1 = {
  field1: [],
  field2: [],
  field3: undefined
}
const filters2 = {
  field1: undefined,
  field2: undefined,
  field3: []
}
const filters3 = {
  field1: [1, 2, 3],
  field2: [1],
  field3: {}
}
const hasLength = x => x && x.length;
const hasActiveFilters1 = Object.values(filters1).some(hasLength);
const hasActiveFilters2 = Object.values(filters2).some(hasLength);
const hasActiveFilters3 = Object.values(filters3).some(hasLength);
console.log(hasActiveFilters1); // false
console.log(hasActiveFilters2); // false
console.log(hasActiveFilters3); // true
```